# How to customize posts tags meta box

Tags: wordpress

How to customise posts tags meta box and make similar to like post categories meta box with tags parents relation and just same ui as category meta box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between the tags and categries is that tag is not hierarchical while categories are. Now to make the tags hierarchichal please  paste the below code to your functions.php.

```
function hierarchical_tags() {

  // rewrite functionality of WordPress tags

  global $wp_rewrite;

  $rewrite =  array(
    'hierarchical'              => false, // Maintains tag permalink structure
    'slug'                      => get_option('tag_base') ? get_option('tag_base') : 'tag',
    'with_front'                => ! get_option('tag_base') || $wp_rewrite->using_index_permalinks(),
    'ep_mask'                   => EP_TAGS,
  );

  // tag labels

  $labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Tags', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Tag', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Taxonomy', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Tags', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Tag', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Tag', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove tags', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Tags', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Tags', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'hierarchical_tags' ),
  );

  // Override built-in WordPress tags

  register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', 'post', array(
    'hierarchical'              => true, // Was false, now set to true
    'query_var'                 => 'tag',
    'labels'                    => $labels,
    'rewrite'                   => $rewrite,
    'public'                    => true,
    'show_ui'                   => true,
    'show_admin_column'         => true,
    '_builtin'                  => true,
  ) );

}
add_action('init', 'hierarchical_tags');
```

Comment: How to get tags parent